# Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6,or later

Tags: php, magento2

I am using `magento2.2.3` version and php version is `7.1.8`.

But whenever I run commands, 
I get this message:

```
Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html
```

Also `admin store` is not loaded properly. Menu options are not working. CSS and js are not working properly.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

magento core checks if `PHP_VERSION_ID` is set and has right version number.

```
if (!defined('PHP_VERSION_ID') || !(PHP_VERSION_ID === 70002 || PHP_VERSION_ID === 70004 || PHP_VERSION_ID >= 70006)) {
    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
        echo 'Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. ' .
            'Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html';
    }
...
```

so you have to check which value your `PHP_VERSION_ID` has